# factanal() not working when I try to run it

Tags: r

I am trying to run factanal on a correlation matrix in r. But when I do, I get the error
`error in solve.default(cv) : system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.56586e-18`
The code I am using:

```
library("psych")
data(Reise)
Reise.fa <- factanal(Reise, factors = 5)
```

The matrix is a correlation matrix so it should be singular, I'm not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: Because `Reise` is a correlation matrix you need to use `factanal(factors = 5, covmat = Reise)`.

Comment: As mentioned by @RitchieSacramento, you just need to tell `factanal` that `Reise` is your `covmat`. read more `?factanal` . Proof that it works with that minor change: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGuEz.png